# Lesser than or greater than in Swift switch statement

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I am familiar with `switch` statements in Swift, but wondering how to replace this piece of code with a `switch`:

```
if someVar < 0 {
    // do something
} else if someVar == 0 {
    // do something else
} else if someVar > 0 {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, I think the code using switch is far less readable than the if statements. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Here's one approach. Assuming `someVar` is an `Int` or other `Comparable`, you can optionally assign the operand to a new variable. This lets you scope it however you want using the `where` keyword:

```
var someVar = 3

switch someVar {
case let x where x < 0:
    print("x is \(x)")
case let x where x == 0:
    print("x is \(x)")
case let x where x > 0:
    print("x is \(x)")
default:
    print("this is impossible")
}
```

This can be simplified a bit:

```
switch someVar {
case _ where someVar < 0:
    print("someVar is \(someVar)")
case 0:
    print("someVar is 0")
case _ where someVar > 0:
    print("someVar is \(someVar)")
default:
    print("this is impossible")
}
```

You can also avoid the `where` keyword entirely with range matching:

```
switch someVar {
case Int.min..<0:
    print("someVar is \(someVar)")
case 0:
    print("someVar is 0")
default:
    print("someVar is \(someVar)")
}
```

Comment: I recommend `default: fatalError()` to detect possible logic errors early.

Comment: Thanks! These examples are very helpful and they solve my issue! (other examples were good too, but yours were most helpful to me)

Comment: @MartinR `assertionFailure` seems to be a safer option, especially when working in a team.

Answer (score 189):

With Swift 5, you can choose one of the following switch in order to replace your if statement.

---

#### #1 Using switch with `PartialRangeFrom` and `PartialRangeUpTo`

```
let value = 1

switch value {
case 1...:
    print("greater than zero")
case 0:
    print("zero")
case ..<0:
    print("less than zero")
default:
    fatalError()
}
```

---

#### #2 Using switch with `ClosedRange` and `Range`

```
let value = 1

switch value {
case 1 ... Int.max:
    print("greater than zero")
case Int.min ..< 0:
    print("less than zero")
case 0:
    print("zero")
default:
    fatalError()
}
```

---

#### #3 Using switch with where clause

```
let value = 1

switch value {
case let val where val > 0:
    print("\(val) is greater than zero")
case let val where val == 0:
    print("\(val) is zero")
case let val where val < 0:
    print("\(val) is less than zero")
default:
    fatalError()
}
```

---

#### #4 Using switch with where clause and assignment to `_`

```
let value = 1

switch value {
case _ where value > 0:
    print("greater than zero")
case _ where value == 0:
    print("zero")
case _ where value < 0:
    print("less than zero")
default:
    fatalError()
}
```

---

#### #5 Using switch with `RangeExpression` protocol's `~=(_:_:)` operator

```
let value = 1

switch true {
case 1... ~= value:
    print("greater than zero")
case ..<0 ~= value:
    print("less than zero")
default:
    print("zero")
}
```

---

#### #6 Using switch with `Equatable` protocol's `~=(_:_:)` operator

```
let value = 1

switch true {
case value > 0:
    print("greater than zero")
case value < 0:
    print("less than zero")
case 0 ~= value:
    print("zero")
default:
    fatalError()
}
```

---

#### #7 Using switch with `PartialRangeFrom`, `PartialRangeUpTo` and `RangeExpression`'s `contains(_:)` method

```
let value = 1

switch true {
case (1...).contains(value):
    print("greater than zero")
case (..<0).contains(value):
    print("less than zero")
default:
    print("zero")
}
```

Comment: why is the defaults case needed in #2? seems flakey that if the rannge is from Int.min to Int.max what is left?

Comment: Wow, nice list of options. Good to know there are a number of ways to do this.

Comment: Good overview but flawed because numbers between 0 and 1 are unaccounted for. `0.1` throws a fatal error because `1...` covers only numbers from 1. So this solution only works if `value` is an `Int` but that is dangerous because if the variable type changes the functionality breaks without any compiler error.

Comment: Your solution does not work correctly for Double type.
case 1...:
    print("greater than zero") 
Is NOT greater than 0 it is greater or equal to 1.

Answer (score 22):

The `switch` statement, under the hood, uses the `~=` operator. So this:

```
let x = 2

switch x {
case 1: print(1)
case 2: print(2)
case 3..<5: print(3..<5)
default: break
}
```

Desugars to this:

```
if 1          ~= x { print(1) }
else if 2     ~= x { print(2) }
else if 3..<5 ~= x { print(3..<5) }
else {  }
```

[If you look at the standard library reference, it can tell you exactly what the `~=` is overloaded to do](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/opfunc/s:ZFSsoi2teuRq_Ss12IntervalType_FTq_qq_S_5Bound_Sb): included is range-matching, and equating for equatable things. (Not included is enum-case matching, which is a language feature, rather than a function in the std lib)

You'll see that it doesn't match a straight boolean on the left-hand-side. For those kind of comparisons, you need to add a where statement.

Unless... you overload the `~=` operator yourself. (This is generally *not* recommended) One possibility would be something like this:

```
func ~= <T> (lhs: T -> Bool, rhs: T) -> Bool {
  return lhs(rhs)
}
```

So that matches a function that returns a boolean on the left to its parameter on the right. Here's the kind of thing you could use it for:

```
func isEven(n: Int) -> Bool { return n % 2 == 0 }

switch 2 {
case isEven: print("Even!")
default:     print("Odd!")
}
```

For your case, you might have a statement that looks like this:

```
switch someVar {
case isNegative: ...
case 0: ...
case isPositive: ...
}
```

But now you have to define new `isNegative` and `isPositive` functions. Unless you overload some more operators...

You can overload normal infix operators to be curried prefix or postfix operators. Here's an example:

```
postfix operator < {}

postfix func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T)(_ rhs: T) -> Bool {
  return lhs < rhs
}
```

This would work like this:

```
let isGreaterThanFive = 5<

isGreaterThanFive(6) // true
isGreaterThanFive(5) // false
```

Combine that with the earlier function, and your switch statement can look like this:

```
switch someVar {
case 0< : print("Bigger than 0")
case 0  : print("0")
default : print("Less than 0")
}
```

Now, you probably shouldn't use this kind of thing in practice: it's a bit dodgy. You're (probably) better off sticking with the `where` statement. That said, the switch statement pattern of

```
switch x {
case negative:
case 0:
case positive:
}
```

or

```
switch x {
case lessThan(someNumber):
case someNumber:
case greaterThan(someNumber):
}
```

Seems common enough for it to be worth considering.

Comment: where is your answer to the question? I can't find it.

Comment: case 3..<5: print(3..<5) - Literally in the first paragraph. This answer is underrated. Saves me so much code.

Answer (score 15):

You can:

```
switch true {
case someVar < 0:
    print("less than zero")
case someVar == 0:
    print("eq 0")
default:
    print("otherwise")
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This is how it looks like with ranges

```
switch average {
case 0..<40: //greater or equal than 0 and less than 40
    return "T"
case 40..<55: //greater or equal than 40 and less than 55
    return "D"
case 55..<70: //greater or equal than 55 and less than 70
    return "P"
case 70..<80: //greater or equal than 70 and less than 80
    return "A"
case 80..<90: //greater or equal than 80 and less than 90
    return "E"
case 90...100: //greater or equal than 90 and less or equal than 100
    return "O"
default:
    return "Z"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Glad that Swift 4 addresses the problem:

As a workaround in 3 I did:

```
switch translation.x  {
case  0..<200:
    print(translation.x, slideLimit)
case  -200..<0:
    print(translation.x, slideLimit)
default:
    break
}
```

Works but not ideal

Answer (score 6):

Since someone has already posted `case let x where x < 0:` here is an alternative for where `someVar` is an `Int`.

```
switch someVar{
case Int.min...0: // do something
case 0: // do something
default: // do something
}
```

And here is an alternative for where `someVar` is a `Double`:

```
case -(Double.infinity)...0: // do something
// etc
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 is nice and clean now

```
switch array.count {
case 3..<.max: 
    print("Array is greater than or equal to 3")
case .min..<3:
    print("Array is less than 3")
default:
    break
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<0` expression doesn't work (anymore?) so I ended up with this:

**Swift 3.0:**

```
switch someVar {
    case 0:
        // it's zero
    case 0 ..< .greatestFiniteMagnitude:
        // it's greater than zero
    default:
        // it's less than zero
    }
```

Comment: In swift 3.0, `X_MAX` has been replaced by `.greatestFiniteMagnitude`, ie `Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude`, `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` etc. So usually, you can just do `case 0..< .greatestFiniteMagnitude` since the type of `someVar` is already known

Comment: @Dorian Roy `var timeLeft = 100` `switch timeLeft {case 0...<=7200:
            print("ok")  default:print("nothing") }` Why is the  `<=` operator not recognized?  If I write it without the equal it works. Thanks

Comment: @bibscy You want to use the closed range operator: `case 0...7200:` The operator `<=` is a comparison operator. In a switch you can only use range operators [(see docs)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1851035-swift_standard_library_operators)

Comment: This was great. I was getting this error **expression pattern of type 'Range<Double>' cannot match values of type 'Int'** because my `someVar` was an `Int` and I had to do `Double(`someVar)` to make it work...

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest solution I could come up with:

```
switch someVar {
case ..<0:
    // do something
case 0:
    // do something else
default:
    // etc
}
```