# Fatal error: Range end index has no valid successor

Tags: swift, switch-statement, fatal-error, exc-bad-instruction

So i have a problem using the Switch statement, when i used it with a range i get this "Fatal error: Range end index has no valid successor" in the console.

```
var ArrayBytes : [UInt8] = [48 ,48 ,48]
 var SuperArrayMensaje : Array = [[UInt8]]()
var num7BM : Array = [UInt8]()

    for var Cont27 = 0; Cont27 < 800; Cont27++ {

        ArrayBytesReservaSrt = String(Mensaje7BM[Cont27])

        switch Mensaje7BM[Cont27] {

        case 0...9 :
                     num7BM = Array(ArrayBytesReservaSrt.utf8)
                     ArrayBytes.insert(num7BM[0], atIndex: 2)

        case 10...99 :
                     num7BM = Array(ArrayBytesReservaSrt.utf8)
                     ArrayBytes.insert(num7BM[0], atIndex: 1)
                     ArrayBytes.insert(num7BM[1], atIndex: 2)

        case 100...255 : // --> THE problem is here "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"
                     num7BM = Array(ArrayBytesReservaSrt.utf8) 
                     ArrayBytes.insert(num7BM[0], atIndex: 0)
                     ArrayBytes.insert(num7BM[1], atIndex: 1)
                     ArrayBytes.insert(num7BM[2], atIndex: 2)


        default : break

        }

    SuperArrayMensaje.insert(ArrayBytes, atIndex: Cont27)

                ArrayBytes = [48 ,48 ,48]
    }
```

Comment: Can you give info of `Mensaje7BM`?

Comment: It's not really needed.  The type being switched on is `UInt8`.

Comment: Related: [Lesser than or greater than in Swift switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31656642/2792531)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can be reproduced with this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
let u = 255 as UInt8

switch u {
case 0...9: print("one")
case 10...99: print("two")
case 100...255: print("three")
}
```

And to a degree, we see the problem if we simply try to create a range variable that would cover this range:

```
let r = Range<UInt8>(start: 100, end: 256)
```

This doesn't compile.  First, we must note that the `end` argument for the `Range` constructor is not included in the range.

The range `100...255` is equivalent to `100..<256`.  If we try to construct that range, we get the compile error:

> Integer literal '256' overflows when stored into 'UInt8'

We can't create a range which *includes* the max value for that integer type.  Problematically, there's no `UInt8` value larger than `255`.  That's needed because for something to be contained within a range, it must be smaller than the `end` value of the range.  That is, it must return true when compared with the `<` operator.  And there's no `UInt8` value that can make this statement: `255 < n` return true.  Therefore, `255` can never be in a range of type `UInt8`.

So, we have to find a different approach.

As the programmer, we can know that the range we're trying to create representing all the three digit decimal numbers that fit in `UInt8`, we could just use the `default` case here:

```
let u = 255 as UInt8

switch u {
case 0...9: print("one")
case 10...99: print("two")
default: print("three")
}
```

This seems the simplest solution.  I like this option best because we don't end up with a `default` case that we know will never execute.

If we *really* explicitly want a case that captures all of the values from `100` to `UInt8` max, we can also do this:

```
switch u {
case 0...9: print("one")
case 10...99: print("two")
case 100..<255, 255: print("three")
default: print("how did we end up here?")
}
```

Or like this:

```
switch u {
case 0...9: print("one")
case 10...99: print("two")
case 100...255 as ClosedInterval: print("three")
default: print("default")
}
```

For more reading on the `ClosedInterval`, see the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ClosedInterval_Structure/index.html) or [Swift doc](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/ClosedInterval/).