# Switch case with range

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm learning Swift and tried to program the game "Bullseye" from Ryan Wenderlich by my own before watching the videos.

I needed to give the user points depending on how close to the target number he was. I tried to calculate the difference and than check the range and give the user the points, This is what I did with If-else (Couldn't do it with switch case):

```
private func calculateUserScore() -> Int {
    let diff = abs(randomNumber - Int(bullsEyeSlider.value))
    if diff == 0 {
        return PointsAward.bullseye.rawValue
    } else if diff < 10 {
        return PointsAward.almostBullseye.rawValue
    } else if diff < 30 {
        return PointsAward.close.rawValue
    }
    return 0 // User is not getting points. 
}
```

Is there a way to do it more elegantly or with Switch-Case?
I couldn't just do `diff == 0` for example in the case in switch case as xCode give me an error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lesser than or greater than in Swift switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656642/lesser-than-or-greater-than-in-swift-switch-statement)

Comment: `case 0: return PointsAward.bullseye.rawValue` and `case 1..<10: return PointsAward.almostBullseye.rawValue`, etc...

Comment: It's hard to see the point of using an enum PointsAward since you are only interested in the rawValue. Do you use the enum elsewhere in your code?

Comment: No, I'm new to Swift and just wanted to try using basic enums. Yeah, it's not really needed I agree with you.

Comment: Dude its so funny, I also googled this while doing the same bullseye app on the RW. Seems like RW is everywhere!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This should work.

```
private func calculateUserScore() -> Int {
    let diff = abs(randomNumber - Int(bullsEyeSlider.value))
    switch diff {
    case 0:
        return PointsAward.bullseye.rawValue
    case 1..<10:
        return PointsAward.almostBullseye.rawValue
    case 10..<30:
        return PointsAward.close.rawValue
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

It's there in the [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) book under Control Flow -> Interval Matching.

Answer (score 16):

In case that you need to check if a value is bigger than any number or between 2 values use it is possible to use `where` instead of `if` looks a bit cleaner this will work

```
func isOutdated(days: Int) -> Outdated {

    var outdatedStatus = Outdated.none

    switch days {
    case _ where days < 5:
        outdatedStatus = .tooLow
    case 5...10:
        outdatedStatus = .low
    case 11...20:
        outdatedStatus = .high
    case _ where days > 20:
        outdatedStatus = .expired
    default:
        outdatedStatus = .none
    }
    return outdatedStatus
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also write `case ..<5` and `case 20...` — leave out the lower or upper bound.

Comment: @PDK tnx for fixing the typo :)

Comment: I wonder why the default is needed? Wouldn't the other cases match all possible Int values between INT_MIN & INT_MAX?

Answer (score 9):

You can return the values you want accordingly:

```
switch diff {
case 0:
    print("Bull Eye")
case 1..<10:
    print("Almost Bull Eye")
case 10..<30:
    print("Close")
default:
    print("Too Far")
}
```

Comment: switch cases in Swift break by themselves. If you need a fallthrough, you need to mention it explicitly.

Comment: Aaah dint know that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Only for you:

```
enum PointsAward: Int {
    case close
    case almostBullseye
    case bullseye
}

private func calculateUserStory() -> Int {
    let bullsEyeSliderValue = 9
    let randomNumber = 100
    let diff = abs(randomNumber - Int(bullsEyeSliderValue))
    switch diff {
    case 0:
        return PointsAward.bullseye.rawValue
    case 0..<10:
        return PointsAward.almostBullseye.rawValue
    case 0..<30:
        return PointsAward.close.rawValue
    default: return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use range-operators as case in switch-statement:

> `a...b` // It have range from a to b, means b is included as well
>
> `a..<b` // It have range from a to b-1, means b is not included

```
private func calculateUserScore() -> Int {
    let diff = abs(randomNumber - Int(bullsEyeSlider.value))
    switch diff {
    case 0: return PointsAward.bullseye.rawValue
    case 1..<10: return PointsAward.almostBullseye.rawValue
    case 10..<30: return PointsAward.close.rawValue
    default: return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the compiler took CGFloat as a closed range of double, so I had to explicitly tell compiler that I am checking CGFloat range.

```
   var progress: CGFloat!
   switch CGFloat(progress) {
    case 0 ... 0.25:
        barColor = .red
    case 0.25 ... 0.5:
        barColor = .yellow
    default:
        break
    }
```