# How to calculate height based on item count in swift

Tags: swift, math

How do I archive this result using a simple mathematical formula.

I have an initial `offset = 100`, and initial `count = 0`, that i want to increase the offset based on `count` value. I tried using the below code but it doesn't function correctly.

Example

1. When count is `0` to `3`, then offset should be `100`.
2. When count is
   `4` to `6`, then offset should be `200`.
3. When count is `7` to `9`,
   then offset should be `300`.
4. When count is `10` to `12`, then offset
   should be `400`.

Attempt

```
func getHeight(count: Int) ->CGFloat {
     var index = 0
     for i in 0..<count{
         if(i % 2  != 0){
             index += 1
         }
     }
    return CGFloat(100 * index)
    //return CGFloat(count + 3 / 9 * 100)
}
```

Testing

```
print("0 to 3 = \(self.getHeight(count: 0)), expected = 100")
print("0 to 3 = \(self.getHeight(count: 2)), expected = 100")
print("4 to 6 = \(self.getHeight(count: 4)), expected = 200")
print("7 to 9 = \(self.getHeight(count: 7)), expected = 300")
print("10 to 12 = \(self.getHeight(count: 12)), expected = 400")
```

Results

```
0 to 3 = 0.0, expected = 100
0 to 3 = 100.0, expected = 100
4 to 6 = 200.0, expected = 200
7 to 9 = 300.0, expected = 300
10 to 12 = 600.0, expected = 400
```

Comment: switch case with range value should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665744/switch-case-with-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula with integer division:

```
let cnt = count != 0 ? count : 1
result = 100 * ((cnt + 2) / 3)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `count = 0` though

Comment: @Alladinian Yes, I have not noticed wider range at 0

Comment: An alternative  to the ternary operator is to use a `guard` statement `guard count > 0 else { return 100 }`

Comment: or without a guard: `max(1, (count + 2) / 3) * 100.0`