# Any way to have a string selected based on an int without a bunch of if statements?

Tags: swift

I am creating an app that needs to change a label based on an integer value, there are ten different labels and 13 different integer options. Does anyone know of a way to convert it without using a bunch of if statements? Also the original value does need to be an int as it is assigned based on a UIPicker.

```
if class1Grade == 1 {
            class1LetterGrade = "A+"
        } else if class1Grade == 2 {
            class1LetterGrade = "A"
        }
```

It needs to do conversion along these lines. Just wanted to check if there was a way that could save me from writing an extra few hundred lines of code.

Comment: Try a `switch` with ranges: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52665973/14351818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary:

```swift
func letterGrade(_ grade: Int) -> String? {
  return [
    1: "A+",
    2: "A",
    3: "B",
  ][grade]
}

letterGrade(1) // "A+"
letterGrade(2) // "A"
letterGrade(7) // nil
```

Comment: working fine..........