# How to specify a range to avoid in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make it so when I provide a value that isn't in the thirties it prints out a certain message. Here is my code:

```
let age = 25

if case 18...25 = age {
  print("Cool demographic")
}
else if case !(30...39) = age {
  print("not in there thirties")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern match operator `~=`

```
static func ~= (pattern: Range<Bound>, value: Bound) -> Bool
```

> You can use this pattern matching operator (~=) to test whether a
>   value is included in a range. The following example uses the ~=
>   operator to test whether an integer is included in a range of
>   numbers.

```
let age = 29

if 18...25 ~= age {
    print("Cool demographic")
} else if !(30...39 ~= age) {
    print("not in there thirties") // "not in there thirties\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like `contains` rather than the unnecessarily obscure `if case`. There are situations where `if case` is needed, but this is not one of them. It's good to say what you mean. So:

```
let age = 25

if (18...25).contains(age) {
    print("Cool demographic")
}
else if !(30...39).contains(age) {
    print("not in their thirties")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `age` is an integer, you can do a direct comparison:

```
if age < 30 || age > 39 {
    print("not in thirties")
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked ! Why didn't I think of that :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `switch`, in my opinion it's a little bit more expressive than `if-else`:

```
let age = 25

switch age {
case 18...25:
    print("Cool demographic")
case _ where !(30...39 ~= age):
    print("not in there thirties")
default:
    break
}
```

You can find good examples with `switch` from Imanou Petit by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656642/lesser-than-or-greater-than-in-swift-switch-statement):